# Defining a non-empty list through a type

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a non-empty list in the type system with typescript. I know that I could define a list of `n` elements, similar to a Tuple:

```js
type TwoElementList = [number, number];
```

But this would only work for lists of a predefined length.

I'm looking at the popular CIS 194 course on Haskell, which gives an example of defining a non-empty list using the type system:

```hs
data NonEmptyList a = NEL a [a]
```

I *think* this isn't possible in typescript; but I am wondering if anyone can confirm that.

---

In the part of CIS 914 which defines `NonEmptyList`, we see the conversions between this 'interface' and that of a standard list:

```hs
nelToList :: NonEmptyList a -> [a]
nelToList (NEL x xs) = x:xs

listToNel :: [a] -> Maybe (NonEmptyList a)
listToNel []     = Nothing
listToNel (x:xs) = Just $ NEL x xs
```

So as @JeffreyWesterkamp points out, an equivalent in typescript would indeed have a different interface than a standard list, and indeed we could create functions to translate between the interface `[number, [number]]` and `[number]`.

To illustrate what I'm getting at, though, consider the following typescript:

```js
type NumberPair = [number, number];

const x: NumberPair = [1, 1];
const y = x[2];
```

Here Typescript will show a compilation error because we cannot access `[2]` on `NumberPair`. Similarly for lists of non-fixed length, the type of an element at an index is the union `T | undefined`; understandable because we don't know if the index `i` is present on a list. But in a non-empty list, we can always guarantee that the index `0` is present. What I'm wondering is whether it's possible to have typescript determine from a type signature that it will always be able to get at least 1 element from a type.

Comment: If you can define a type that stores two parameters with the last one a list, you can define a non-empty list.

Comment: A non-empty is not a "special" type in Haskell, in essence it is just a type that has two fields, a "head" which is the first element, and a "tail" wich is a list (that can be empty). You simply see the head as the first element, and thus therefore the list has an element.

Comment: So you can define it as `type NonEmpty = [number, [number]]` for example. Here the first element acts as the "head", and the second as the rest of the elements..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you; that's a useful perspective; it does answer my question to some degree, the only issue is that a type of `[number, [number]]` presents a different interface to a standard list; as I say, I'm guessing this isn't possible in typescript

Comment: Isn't it that `NonEmptyList a` is in a similar way a different interface to `[a]` too?

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp I think you're completely correct; I've updated the question to try and give more detail on what I'm looking for

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp: well the point is that Haskell libraries have functionality for `NonEmpty` like `fmap`, `group`, etc. As a result it "is" a non-empty list. As a textbook once said: "Data types only exist by the grace of functions.". It is not the `data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]` that makes it a non-empty list, it is because functions "see" it as a non-empty list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh yes for sure, but `NonEmptyList a` still won't work with the list-specific functions like `head` or `tail`. (That's about as far as the comparison between HS and TS stretches). In that sense it is different from `[a]` as `number[]` is to `[number, number[]]` in TS.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp: that is why the defined [`head :: NonEmpty a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:head) and of course the fact that the `head` from `Prelude` does not work on `NonEmpty a` is here a benefit to not "accidently" use it. One could in fact define `head` in terms of `Foldable`, and then thus make a `head :: Foldable f => f a -> a` that would work both on `[a]` and `NonEmpty a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is indeed possible!

```
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];
```

Comment: This is great! I'm continually amazed by typescript, thanks for this

Comment: Yeah it's a great tool! Cheers!